# How to setting up a simple Debian 7 as a gateway?

Tags: debian, gateway

I want to use a dedicated Debian 7 machine as a gateway for a LAN in my home.

My machine has two network cards eth1 (external Internet) and eth2 internal LAN.

This eth2 is the one which has an IP address like 192.3.1.1 and is used as the default gateway for your internal machines.

I saw this [article](https://www.debian-administration.org/article/23/Setting_up_a_simple_Debian_gateway) but the script is outdated for Debian 7.

How can I setting up a simple Debian 7 as a gateway?

Comment: You might want to use Debian 8 which has just been released. Apart from that, I don't see anything wrong with the article you linked, what problems do you have with it?

Comment: @wurtel did you see that script don't have LBS header?

Comment: Sure, it's not an `init.d` script. So?

Comment: @wurtel ok, but where I put in /etc/network/if-up.d/ ? I choose the name for this script?

Comment: Yes, just make sure there are no dots, e.g. `gateway` EDIT: and make sure it's executable, and the script begins with `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/sh`

Comment: @wurtel right, but I have more questions, how can I make it executable, and if is necessary to change in /etc/network/interfaces ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to checkout Shorewall, is a tool for configuring iptables. Its really easy and powerful. Shorewall is in debian repos, you can install it with apt-get.

And theres some preconfigured files for the two interfaces setup in:

```
/usr/share/doc/shorewall/examples
```

Some useful documentation:

http://www.shorewall.net/two-interface.htm

https://wiki.debian.org/HowTo/shorewall